# CancellationException from SpeechClient after 30 seconds

Tags: java

I am using the java client library google-cloud-speech version "1.22.1", to do async speech Recognition on files located on google cloud. (Using a gs:// url).

This works fine for small audio files, but if google can't finish the job in 30 seconds, it throws the exception "java.util.concurrent.CancellationException" Task was cancelled and I get no result.

Is there any way to increase the timeout?
My code to wait for the response is:

```
    OperationFuture<LongRunningRecognizeResponse, LongRunningRecognizeMetadata>response=speechClient.longRunningRecognizeAsync(config,audio);

    while (!response.isDone()) {
      System.out.println("Waiting for response...");
      Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
    System.out.println("Build done");
    List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.get().getResultsList();
    System.out.println("results.size=" + results.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem. In my case I changed the version to "1.0.0" and it worked. Of course this is subject to whether for your purposes you can change the version.

In the pom.xml file change the version

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-speech</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```